# Serial UART interceptty capture. Can't make heads or tails of it

Tags: serial-port, uart, packet-sniffers

I'm working on understanding a mystery protocol in a DLP 3d printer. A raspberry pi is talking to a motor/led controller via a serial bus. The device seems to be proprietary but I'm guessing it uses some kind of open standard (like GCode). It may help to know the device was probably made and programmed in china. No idea if this factors but there may be some programming cultural thing I'm missing. I'm trying to figure out how to control this motor/led control board via the serial port so I captured data using interceptty.

This seems to be an idle state sent to the mystery device from the pi.

55 55 55 55 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 aa aa aa aa

This tends to be how the mystery device acknowledges

55 55 55 55 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 aa aa aa aa 
55 55 55 55 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 aa aa aa aa

This seems to be noting an idle state always after acknowledgement from the mystery device.
55 55 55 55 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 58 aa aa aa aa

This is a command that started the print off. So this begins moving a motor.

55 55 55 55 00 03 e8 03 00 00 40 0d 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 3f aa aa aa aa

For reference 55555555 and aaaaaaaa are 01010101 etc in binary. They seem to be a way to clear coms for async serial transmission. It certainly LOOKS like I'm seeing extremely low level communication. As if I hooked a logic analyzer up to the circuit.

There are 16 hex bytes in between each of these clearing/syncing steps. I'm not sure if I'm just seeing VERY low level communication or if these 16 bytes contain all of the data in any given command or the data plus check bytes or something.

Finally, I'm seeing LOTS of repetition. This leads me to think that this isn't Gcode but that the pi is sending a command every cycle and the slave/mystery device is updating as quickly as possible.

For example the output below repeats over and over 1145 times after starting a print. This would be when the motor has descended fully into a vat and an LED is held on for an extended period of time. > denotes received transmissions < denotes outgoing transmissions from the pi.

```
>  55 55 55 55 00 03 00 00 00 00 | UUUU      
>  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 04 |           
>  aa aa aa aa 55 55 55 55 00 03 |     UUUU  
>  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |           
>  00 00 01 04 aa aa aa aa       |           
<  55 55 55 55 00 03 20 03 00 00 | UUUU      
<  78 5d 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 fd | x]        
<  aa aa aa aa                   |
```

I'm hoping to get some direction. None of this hex seems to translate well into ascii or utf. I don't think it's passing ints or chars. Maybe it's backwards bitwise? I'm not sure. I'm having lots of trouble making heads or tails of it.

What level is UUUU and aaaa at? It seems like something you'd see on a logic analyzer not from through a driver.

Anyway, any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the 55/55/55/55 and aa/aa/aa/aa are framing around each message of 16 bytes. Three dimensions plus LED intensity makes four things to control, perhaps there are four bytes per dimension. Can you make it step 1 unit in one dimension and see the change in the messages? Then step 1 unit in another dimension, and so on. Can you control the LED brightness - if so increase it one unit without changing the position. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Good tips. This board controls 1 axis stepper. It has ports for 3 limit switches, a number of fans, two other motors, 2 LEDs, And uses a serial bus to relay commands to a second controller. 

The 55/55/55/55 and aa/aa/aa/aa look like UART syncing. Exactly 16 transitions each. I thought maybe the pi driver is filling a buffer because the UART doesn't frame and make its own packets. If that was the case then every 8 bits should have a start and stop bit if they used 8N1. That would shift the data a bit or two.

No dice. The start/stop bits don't line up as far as I can see.

Comment: You know, I may connect the uart port on the pi to a laptop or something and see if I can capture data through it. That way I know what I transmitted and maybe I can tear apart the pattern.

Comment: A uart doesn’t need syncing - that’s what the start and stop bits do. But an app can add framing around a message so it’s clear where it starts/stops, and can be checked to ensure the message content is found,, although I’ve never seen four bytes before as well as four bytes after, but maybe there’s an advantage that you then don’t need a checksum/CRC? I’d focus on the 16 bytes in-between.

Comment: You're right, of course. For future reading, UART does have to sync but it does this by oversampling on the Rx. Usually this is anywhere from 8-16x per bit. So Rx is actually sampling the line 8-16x baud rate and averaging the bits.

To give myself some credit this was not a quick google. I saw mentions of UART needing to sync and it made sense since the two devices could be on different clocks and bits wouldn't start in exactly the same place every time. UART doesn't have a clock line so you have to find a way to sync up. This is an odd framing though, as you said.

Comment: For future reading, a UART syncs itself, i.e. you don’t have to explicitly or externally sync it by sending some specific data.